# .htaccess RewriteRules with nested files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/task/([^/]+)/?$ api/task/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/task/skills/([^/]+)?$ api/task/skills.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**folder structure**

```
/api/task/index.php
/api/task/skills.php
```

**Url usage**

```
/api/task/1
/api/task/skills/1
```

When I try to access `/api/task/skills/1` it ends up firing the content of `index.php` instead of `skills.php`

Could anyone help out to show me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Put the skills before index

Comment: That actually won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `mod_rewrite` looping due to this regex in your first rule: `^api/task/([^/]+)/?$` which also matches `/api/task/skills.php` and `/api/task/index.php`

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

# skip further rules for real files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/task/([^/]+)/?$ api/task/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/task/skills/([^/]+)?$ api/task/skills.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```